# In Java, Does Object of some class created in superclass can be used in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class A
{

    class B b;

    B b = new b();
}

class B extends A

{

    b.function();

}
```

Here can B use the same object created in A?

Comment: Why don't you try it and let us know? ;) :) :)

Comment: (Writing valid Java helps. Also, [read the existing introductions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)).

Comment: you've got invalid syntax ,fix that to make your question more meaningful

Comment: Got  java.lang.NullPointerException, public class C {
 public String  cvariable;
 
  public void cfunction(){
   
      System.out.println("string");   
   
  }
}
public class A {

 public C c1;
 
 public void funtiona(){
 c1 = new C();
 }
}

public class B extends A {

  
 public void functionb(){
   
   c1.cfunction();
     
  }
 
 public static void main(String args[]){
  
  B b = new B();
  b.functionb();
  
 }
 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is your program:

```
class C { 
    public String cvariable; 
    public void cfunction(){ 
        System.out.println("string");   
    }
} 

class A { 
    public C c1; 
    public void funtiona(){ 
        c1 = new C(); 
    } 
} 

public class B extends A { 
    public void functionb(){ 
        c1.cfunction(); 
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        B b = new B(); 
        b.functionb(); 
    } 
}
```

It is correctly throwing null pointer exception. It proceed as follows:

- In the main method you call `functionb()`
- In `functionb()` you call `cfunction()` with c1, but c1 is just an variable of type C(as not initialized yet) which contains null. So getting null pointer exception.

Comment: c1 is instantiated in A, Does c1 cannot be accessed by B object.

Comment: c1 is instantiated but you did not call the `functiona()` where you instantiated the c1. So in this case it is not instantiated

Comment: And one more thing, you can't instantiate a child class object in parent class and use it in the child class...... it will be an infinite loop. See my next answer

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer, we have to call the super class function in sub class to do instantiate of other class mentioned in super class. It do not automatically instantiate if we extend the super class.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

See the following program, It will throw  `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

```
class B{
    A a = new A();
    public B(){
        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
    }
}

public class A extends B{
    public void show(){
        a.hashCode();
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new A().show();
    }
}
```

This is because program goes in the infinite loop, As before creating a child class object it calls the parent class constructor and in parent class for hash code it again calls the child class constructor. so an infinite loop